# How can i send an email with email id and message while i save it in database in laravel 6?

Tags: email, laravel-6

public function html_email(Request $request)
{

```
    $mail = new \App\Mail();
    $mail->name = $request->input('name');
    $mail->email = $request->input('email');
    $mail->message = $request->input('message');
    $mail->save();

    $mail = array('name' => "$request->name");


    Mail::send(['text' => 'mail'], $mail, function ($message) {
        $message->to('test@gmail.com', 'Test Point') **//how can i fetch the email id here in $mail->email ?**
            ->subject('Laravel HTML Testing Mail');//how can i fetch the message here?
        $message->from('xyz@gmail.com', '$name');
    });
    echo "HTML Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
    return view('welcome');

}
```

how can I fetch the data after saving it in the database, and send the data in an email? Basically, I want to use it in contact page.

Comment: Do you have any specific question about this code? Anything not working as expected?

Comment: Also, be warned that Laravel 6 reaches it's end of life in September 2022. You should plan to upgrade to any later version

Comment: @NicoHaase I want to send the '$mail->email' in Mail::send(['text' => 'mail'], $mail, function ($message) {
        $message->to('test@gmail.com', 'Test Point') this line. Can you help me out please?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What keeps you from using the variable you need?

Answer (score -1):

Here the variable declare

```
public function mail(Request $request)
{
    $mail = new \App\Contact();
    $mail->name = $request->input('name');
    $mail->email = $request->input('email');
    $mail->phone = $request->input('phone');
    $mail->message = $request->input('message');
    $mail->save();

    $mail = array('name' => "$request->name", 'messages' => "$request->,message");
    Mail::send([$request->message => 'user.thankyou'], $mail, function ($message) use ($mail, $request) {
        $message->to('abc@gmail.com', $request->name)->subject
        ($request->message, 'sent a message');
        $message->from('xyz@gmail.com', $request->name);
    });
    echo "Basic Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
    return back();

}
```

Comment: Please share more details. Does this code resolve your problem? Then please add some explanation to it, such that others can learn from your answer